# Codecs to play .vob files in Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-media-player, vob, video-codecs

I’m using Windows Vista Home Premium and I cant find codecs for Windows Media Player that allows it to play .vob files.
I know there are other media players that play these files, but I’d like to use WMP for everything.

Do you know of any codec pack or individual codec/filter that adds that capability to WMP??

PS: I’ve already tried K-Lite codec pack, Vista Codec Pack, Media Player Codec Pack.

Comment: If you have tried K-Lite and you still cannot play something then you have done something wrong.  I have yet to run into a file that K-Lite Mega will not play, and all versions of K-Lite will handle `.vob`

Comment: @typoknig: You cant play them with WMP when the file is in your harddrive (unlike other players). And my question ultimately asks for that, i.e. to play back a .vob file not a DVD.

Comment: @GetFree yes you can. K-Lite is the only codec pack i use and i have been playing DVDs back from hard drive for many years now. Maybe you have a conflicting codec pack installed.

Comment: @typoknig: I’m not talking about playing DVDs back. I’m talking about playing .vob files. Put a .vob file alone in a folder and try to play it back with WMP; does it work? (It will with player like VLC and others)

Comment: @GetFree I understand what you are saying, and yes it does work.  If you decrypt a DVD to your hard drive you will have 3 types of files, `vob` which contains the actual video, `ifo` which contains information on chapters and menus, and `bup` which is a backup of the `ifo`. If you are missing the `ifo` file associated with a set of `vob` files then a `vob` file will not know how to link to the next one. You can still play a `vob` without the other files, but that `vob` will not be linked to the other `vob` files in the set. You need both `vob` and `ifo` for "DVD like" playback.

Comment: @typoknig: It doesn’t work for me. I’m using WMP 11 and the latest K-Lite Mega pack.

Comment: @GetFree as I said before you probably have some type of codec conflict. If I were in your position I would probably use this as an excuse to format my drive and start fresh.  Install only K-Lite Mega pack for your codecs and you should be ok.  I see you are using Vista, and I don't think that matters, but I should mention that I skipped Vista as an OS, but I know for a fact this works in XP and W7.

Answer (score 2):

KLite mega does this...there is more than one version of klite though...make sure you get klite mega.  Windows media player might not like to play VOBs that don't appear to be on a DVD though...It seems like i got it to see a folder as a dvd once.  MS trying to copy protect stuff.  alternately, you could convert from vob to something WMP friendly.

Comment: It seems you are right. When the file is on a DVD I can play it without problems. But if the file is on my computer WMP refuses to play it arguing it "can’t jump to the requested location in the DVD". Apparently it wont be possible to use WMP for this :(

Comment: have you tried the susbt tool as noted here:http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-132347.html this is how i used to do it...not sure if it still works(I long since switched to linux)

Answer (score 0):

[FFDShow](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) does include a DVD decoder.

Answer (score -1):

Download the [CCCP](http://www.cccp-project.net/), and all your codec problems will be solved. Probably.