# Windows 8 won't play VOB files

Tags: windows-8-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Codecs to play .vob files in Windows Media Player?](https://superuser.com/questions/195247/codecs-to-play-vob-files-in-windows-media-player)

I have installed Windows 8 Developer preview, but when I try to play VOB files using Windows media player, it shows a menu : "Play all music" and when I click it, it shows some music that played before in Media player.

Also I have tried with Windows 7 Codec Pack installed but nothing changed.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Windows 7 Codec Pack since it does not seem to work properly and try to install [K-Lite codec pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download_soft.php?d=6634&s=775). Then run Codec Tweak Tool and figure out what is the default codec for each media type (hoping that Windows 8 codec-related registry structure is similar).

Force non-Microsoft codecs to be default by checking their radio button.